# IL: ldfld vs ldflda

Tags: c#, .net, il

I'm writing a small IL-weaving application using Mono.Cecil, that requires me to manipulate the target assembly on an IL level.

My question is quite simple, but I still find the matter very confusing. *What is the practical difference between the `ldfld` and `ldflda` instructions?*

I have consulted with msdn, and it appears that while `ldfld` fetches the value of the field, `ldflda` gets the address of the field. Okay... but what does this mean? I first thought that the former is used for value types (and string), and the latter for reference types, but I have compiled a C# snippet and checked it in Reflector, and it proved me wrong.

I haven't been able to find any distinct pattern in when the C# compiler emits `ldflda` instead of `ldfld`, and my searches didn't reveal any articles that would explain this. So when to use `ldflda` instead of `ldfld`?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: From your description I suspect it uses ldflda if it needs to either pass the variable into a ref parameter, call a method on it, or assign to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it is used for `struct`ures:

```
struct Counter
{
   public int i;
}

struct Something
{
   public Counter c;
}

Something s;
s.c.i++;
```

I am pretty sure `c` here is loaded by address otherwise it would create a copy of `Counter`. That's why you can't do this with propery.

Comment: +1 You are correct.  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a field to a subroutine as a ref parameter, you should see the compiler emit a ldflda for it in order to obtain the reference to pass in.